# Problema con velocidades en Sublime Text 3

Tags: python

Tengo un consulta sobre Sublime y Python. En la universidad tenemos como primer lenguaje Python, y los profesores recomiendan usar Pycharm. Yo arranqué de todas formas con Sublime, ya que estaba acostumbrado al mismo.

Ahora que estamos trabajando con programas más complejos, noto que Sublime se tarda hasta 5-6 minutos en imprimir/calcular valores que Pycharm imprime al instante. Quería saber si hay alguna forma de hacer que el programa vaya más rápido a la hora de calcular e imprimir valores grandes.

(No es algo de mi PC, probé con otras y me ocurría lo mismo).

Les dejo un ejemplo simple de un programa que me tarda minutos en hacer algo que Pycharm hace al instante:

Módulo principal:

```
import soporte, random


def cargar_vector(servicios):
    for i in range(len(servicios)):
        num = i + 1
        descripciones = ('Limpieza general', 'Limpieza especializada', 'Descarga de materiales', 'Seguridad y mantenimiento de la organización laboral', 'Jardinero')
        desc = random.choice(descripciones)
        tipo = random.randint(0,3)
        imp = round(random.random() * 10000 + 1, 2)
        cantidad = random.randint(1,15)
        servicios[i] = soporte.Trabajo(num, desc, tipo, imp, cantidad)


def mostrar_vector(servicios):
    for i in range(len(servicios)):
        print(soporte.to_string(servicios[i]))



def principal():
    n = int(input('Ingrese la cantidad de trabajos: ')) #Mayor a 0
    servicios = [None] * n
    cargar_vector(servicios)
    mostrar_vector(servicios)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    principal()
```

Módulo 'soporte':

```
class Trabajo:
    def __init__(self, num, desc, tipo, imp, cant):
        self.numero = num
        self.descripcion = desc
        self.tipo = tipo
        self.importe = imp
        self.cantidad = cant


def to_string(trabajo):
    cad = 'Número: ' + str(trabajo.numero) + ' - Descripción: ' + trabajo.descripcion + ' - Tipo: ' + str(trabajo.tipo)
    cad += ' - Importe: ' + str(trabajo.importe) + ' - Cantidad: ' + str(trabajo.cantidad)
    return cad
```

Comment: mmm.... dudo que la cosa sea del editor, pero puedes ejecutar tus archivos desde la terminal

Comment: Yo tenía muchos problemas de velocidad con Sublime y python y descubrí que el problema venía del plugin "Anaconda". Si tienes ese paquete instalado, prueba a quitarlo y la velocidad mejorará notablemente.